# Read all .txt file inside a folder by it last edited time

Tags: java, file

I have a code here that can read all .txt file in 1 folder, it can print every content inside the .txt file to console. Then it moved to new folder.

The problem is: it has been read randomly, but i want to read the .txt file by it time-stamp, which is who have last edited time will be read at first...

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Basic {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String source = "C:\\Users\\NN\\Documents\\Test1";
        String target = "C:\\Users\\NN\\Documents\\Test2";

        List<Path> filePaths = filePathsList(source); // Step 1: get all files from a directory
        List<Path> filteredFilePaths = filter(filePaths); // Step 2: filter by ".txt"
        Map<Path, List<String>> contentOfFiles = getContentOfFiles(filteredFilePaths); // Step 3: get content of files
        move(filteredFilePaths, target); // Step 4: move files to destination
        printToConsole(contentOfFiles); // Step 5: print content of files to console
    }

    public static List<Path> filePathsList(String directory) throws IOException {
        List<Path> filePaths = new ArrayList<>();
        DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(directory));
        for (Path path : directoryStream) {
            filePaths.add(path);
        }
        return filePaths;
    }

    private static List<Path> filter(List<Path> filePaths) {
        List<Path> filteredFilePaths = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Path filePath : filePaths) {
            if (filePath.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".txt")) {
                filteredFilePaths.add(filePath);
            }
        }
        return filteredFilePaths;
    }

    private static Map<Path, List<String>> getContentOfFiles(List<Path> filePaths) throws IOException {
        Map<Path, List<String>> contentOfFiles = new HashMap<>();
        for (Path filePath : filePaths) {
            contentOfFiles.put(filePath, new ArrayList<>());
            Files.readAllLines(filePath).forEach(contentOfFiles.get(filePath)::add);
        }
        return contentOfFiles;
    }

    private static void move(List<Path> filePaths, String target) throws IOException {
        Path targetDir = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(target);
        if (!Files.isDirectory(targetDir)) {
            targetDir = Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(target));
        }
        for (Path filePath : filePaths) {
            System.out.println("Moving " + filePath.getFileName() + " to " + targetDir.toAbsolutePath());
            Files.move(filePath, Paths.get(target, filePath.getFileName().toString()), StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
        }   
    }

    private static void printToConsole(Map<Path, List<String>> contentOfFiles) {
        System.out.println("Content of files:");
        contentOfFiles.forEach((k,v) -> v.forEach(System.out::println));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `File.lastModified()` and sort it by its date.

Comment: i must creating a new class or should edit the 2nd step when i filtered the .txt file?